# ruby on rails tutorial - rails 3.0 chapter 11 rspec fails after code listing 11.27

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have run through the book.  I run "rspec spec/" after each step.

Chapter 11 fails starting listin 11.27 adding app/views/pages/home.html.erb
After Listing 11.30. Adding a micropost instance variable to the home action.
app/controllers/pages_controller.rb

Everything is supposed to be working. It isn't.  I am just digging into rails for the very first time.  since this was cut and paste code, I did not expect errors.

I will be grateful for any help in leaning to debug this.  Firure out if I cut and paste wrong, or if Michel's code example is not fully tested.

Here is the rspec output:

MPECHNER-MBP:sample_app michael.pechner$ rspec spec/
..FF.............................................................................................FF....

Failures:

1) MicropostsController POST 'create' failure should not create a micropost
     Failure/Error: post :create, :micropost => @attr
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
       You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
       The error occurred while evaluating nil.errors
     # ./app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__error_messages_html_erb___2864847557408089106_2179824440__3563936241835894680'
     # ./app/views/shared/_micropost_form.html.erb:2:in`block in _app_views_shared__micropost_form_html_erb_**732794408121469484_2179844600__1418926388395345268'
     # ./app/views/shared/_micropost_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__micropost_form_html_erb___732794408121469484_2179844600__1418926388395345268'
     # ./app/views/pages/home.html.erb:6:in`_app_views_pages_home_html_erb**_1781066003698849377_2179862020__1594538359887050056'
     # ./app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:10:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/microposts_controller_spec.rb:34:in`block (5 levels) in '
     # ./spec/controllers/microposts_controller_spec.rb:33:in `block (4 levels) in '

2) MicropostsController POST 'create' failure should render the home page
     Failure/Error: post :create, :micropost => @attr
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
       You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
       The error occurred while evaluating nil.errors
     # ./app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__error_messages_html_erb___2864847557408089106_2179824440__3563936241835894680'
     # ./app/views/shared/_micropost_form.html.erb:2:in`block in _app_views_shared__micropost_form_html_erb_**732794408121469484_2179844600__1418926388395345268'
     # ./app/views/shared/_micropost_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__micropost_form_html_erb___732794408121469484_2179844600__1418926388395345268'
     # ./app/views/pages/home.html.erb:6:in`_app_views_pages_home_html_erb**_1781066003698849377_2179862020__1594538359887050056'
     # ./app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:10:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/microposts_controller_spec.rb:39:in`block (4 levels) in '

3) LayoutLinks when signed in should have a signout link
     Failure/Error: visit root_path
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
       You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
       The error occurred while evaluating nil.errors
     # ./app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__error_messages_html_erb___2864847557408089106_2179824440__3563936241835894680'
     # ./app/views/shared/_micropost_form.html.erb:2:in`block in _app_views_shared__micropost_form_html_erb_**732794408121469484_2179844600__1418926388395345268'
     # ./app/views/shared/_micropost_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__micropost_form_html_erb___732794408121469484_2179844600__1418926388395345268'
     # ./app/views/pages/home.html.erb:6:in`_app_views_pages_home_html_erb**_1781066003698849377_2179862020__1594538359887050056'
     # :10:in `synchronize'
     # ./spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb:51:in`block (3 levels) in '

4) LayoutLinks when signed in should have a profile link
     Failure/Error: visit root_path
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
       You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
       The error occurred while evaluating nil.errors
     # ./app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__error_messages_html_erb___2864847557408089106_2179824440__3563936241835894680'
     # ./app/views/shared/_micropost_form.html.erb:2:in`block in _app_views_shared__micropost_form_html_erb_**732794408121469484_2179844600__1418926388395345268'
     # ./app/views/shared/_micropost_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__micropost_form_html_erb___732794408121469484_2179844600__1418926388395345268'
     # ./app/views/pages/home.html.erb:6:in`_app_views_pages_home_html_erb**_1781066003698849377_2179862020__1594538359887050056'
     # :10:in `synchronize'
     # ./spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb:57:in`block (3 levels) in '

Finished in 2.04 seconds
103 examples, 4 failures
MPECHNER-MBP:sample_app michael.pechner$

Answer (score 8):

I searched git hub for others that have worked through this.
I found it in the posting by https://github.com/mfmcgran
"app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb" seems to be wrong, The code I had showed the first line as "if @users.errors.any?"  ad it needs to be  "if object.errors.any?" 
There was no mention in chapter 11 that this needed to changed. But after this change, all 103 rpsec tests passed.

Comment: OK. I missed it.  It was  a step in chapter 10.  I decided to edit app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb instead of C&P.

Comment: Yep, I made the same mistake. I forgot that if there is no ". . ." in the code sample he means to replace the whole file.

Comment: I had the exact same problem. Changed <% if @users.errors.any? %> to <% if object.errors.any? %> and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial has gotten a little older (given the speed at which gem versions get released). I find its really convenient if you just upgrade to the most recent version of rspec and use capybara instead

```
gem 'capybara'
```

in your Gemfile and

```
gem 'capybara/rspec'
```

in your spec_helper.rb and run

```
bundle install
```

this should then work

```
click_link 'About'
page.should have_content("About")
# in place of
# enter code here`response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Contact")
```

this will continue to work as well

```
get '/about'
response.should have_selector('title', :content => "About")
```